# ¿Por qué solo puedo hacer un canvas de determinadas dimensiones?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```js
var xInic, yInic;
let ptop = 0;
let pleft = 0;
            var estaPulsado = false;
            
            function ratonPulsado(evt) { 
                //Obtener la posición de inicio
                xInic = evt.clientX;
                yInic = evt.clientY;    
                estaPulsado = true;
                //Para Internet Explorer: Contenido no seleccionable
                document.getElementById("cuadro").unselectable = true;
            }
            
            function ratonMovido(evt, left_pos) {
                if(estaPulsado) {
                    //Calcular la diferencia de posición
                    var xActual = evt.clientX;
                    var yActual = evt.clientY;    
                    var xInc = xActual-xInic;
                    var yInc = yActual-yInic;
                    xInic = xActual;
                    yInic = yActual;
                    
                    //Establecer la nueva posición
                    var elemento = document.getElementById("cuadro");
                    var position = getPosicion(elemento);
                    elemento.style.top = (position[0] + yInc) + "px";
                    elemento.style.left = (position[1] + xInc) + "px";
                    ptop = position[0] + yInc
                    pleft = position[1] + xInc
                    return ptop, pleft;

                }
            }
            
            function ratonSoltado(evt) {
                estaPulsado = true;
            }
            
            /*
             * Función para obtener la posición en la que se encuentra el
             * elemento indicado como parámetro.
             * Retorna un array con las coordenadas x e y de la posición
             */
            function getPosicion(elemento) {
                var posicion = new Array(2);
                if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
                    posicion[0] = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elemento, null).getPropertyValue("top"))
                    posicion[1] = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elemento, null).getPropertyValue("left"));
                } else {
                    //Para Internet Explorer
                    posicion[0] = parseInt(elemento.currentStyle.top);             
                    posicion[1] = parseInt(elemento.currentStyle.left);               
                }      
                return posicion;
            }
var el = document.getElementById("cuadro");
            if (el.addEventListener){
                el.addEventListener("mousedown", ratonPulsado, false);
                el.addEventListener("mouseup", ratonSoltado, false);
                document.addEventListener("mousemove", ratonMovido, false);
            } else { //Para IE
                el.attachEvent('onmousedown', ratonPulsado);
                el.attachEvent('onmouseup', ratonSoltado);
                document.attachEvent('onmousemove', ratonMovido);}
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const img = document.getElementById('imagen_1');
const color = document.getElementById('color');
const ctxImagen = canvas.getContext('2d');
let marker = document.getElementById('marker');
const cuadro = document.getElementById('cuadro')

//let h = img.height;

let h = 150;
let w = 300
//let w = img.width;
canvas.style.height = h + 'px';
canvas.style.width = w + 'px';
ctxImagen.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

cuadro.addEventListener('mousemove', () => {
    var rgb = ctxImagen.getImageData(pleft, ptop,8,8).data;
    let red = rgb[0];
    let green = rgb[1];
    let blue = rgb[2];
    let alpha = rgb[3];
    let colores = red + " " + green + " " + blue + " " + alpha;
    //document.getElementById('what').style.background =  'rgba('+red+','+green+', '+blue+', '+alpha+')';
    document.getElementById('what').style.background = 'rgb('+red+','+green+','+blue+')'
    document.getElementById('rf').innerText = ''+red+','+green+','+blue+''
})
```

```css
*
{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
     user-select: none; 
}
.estiloCuadro {
   width: 5px;
   height: 5px;
   border: solid red; 
   position: absolute; 

   cursor: pointer;
   /*Deshabilitar selección de texto*/
   
}
body{
    background: aqua;
}
/*img{
    width: 150px;
}*/
h1
{
    background: red;
    width: 300px;
}
#what{
    
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ASTROLV</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="imagen_1" src="https://htmlcolorcodes.com/assets/images/html-color-codes-color-palette-generators-hero.jpg"  height="150" width="300">
        <span id="he"></span>
        <div id="cuadro" class="estiloCuadro"></div>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <div id="color">
        <h1>El color es: </h1><br>
        <div id="what"></div>
        <p id="rf"></p>
        </div>
        <script src="js/main.js" async></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en el que utilizo una foto y un elemento canvas que la dibuja para poder saber que colores hay en esta foto, el problema es que solo me deja hacer esto con un ancho de foto de 300px y una altura de 150px. Si pongo otros valores el canvas hace zoom sombre la foto y no me deja utilizar todo el area, dejo adjunto el código y unas imágenes. El problema es ese, que si aumento las dimensiones de la foto y las dimensiones del canvas este hace zoom, dejando solo seleccionar lo que se muestra en la pantalla

La imagen de 300x150
[image: Imagen 300x150]

la imágen de 300x300
[image: Imagen ampliada]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he conseguido hacer el programa que quería de la siguiente manera

```js
let imgSource = 'https://i2.wp.com/academiadediseno.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/basica.png?resize=265%2C300&ssl=1'
let h = 200;
let w = 150;

//Cogemos el canvas
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
//Edit de la spropiedades
canvas.setAttribute('height', h);
canvas.setAttribute('width', w);

//Sacamos la posición del mouse
function getElementPosition(obj) {
    var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
        return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
    }
    return undefined;
}

function getEventLocation(element,event){
        var pos = getElementPosition(element);
    
    return {
            x: (event.pageX - pos.x),
        y: (event.pageY - pos.y)
    };
}
//transformar el rgb a # (hex)
function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
        throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
}

//Hacer lo de la imagen pero en plan PRO
function drawImageFromWebUrl(sourceurl){
      var img = new Image();
      var url = sourceurl;
      img.src = url + '?' + new Date().getTime();
      img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', '');
      img.addEventListener("load", function () {
          // The image can be drawn from any source
          canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
          
      });

      img.setAttribute("src", sourceurl);
}

//Pintar en modo dios
drawImageFromWebUrl(imgSource)
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(e){
      var eventLocation = getEventLocation(this,e);
    var coord = "x=" + eventLocation.x + ", y=" + eventLocation.y;

    //Se coge la info del px en el getEventLocation
    var context = this.getContext('2d');
    var pixelData = context.getImageData(eventLocation.x, eventLocation.y, 1, 1).data; 
    

    // si no estas en la imagen ps no la buggues
    if((pixelData[0] == 0) && (pixelData[1] == 0) && (pixelData[2] == 0) && (pixelData[3] == 0)){
                coord += " (O dios mio, no se transformar cosas transparentes a hex)";
    }
    
    //Se define como es el hex
    var hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(pixelData[0], pixelData[1], pixelData[2])).slice(-6);
    
    //El rgb original ps por si hace falta luego
    let rgb = `rgb(${pixelData[0]},${pixelData[1]},${pixelData[2]})`;

    // Mostrar la info
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = coord;
    document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = hex;
    document.getElementById('color_code_hex').innerText = hex
    document.getElementById('color_code_rgb').innerText = rgb
},false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Color detector</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div id="status"></div><br>
<div id="color" style="width:30px;height:30px;"></div>
<div id="color_code_hex"></div>
<div id="color_code_rgb"></div>
<script src="js/color.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```